# Get indices of slices with at least one element obeying some condition

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an ndarray `A` of shape (n, a, b)
I want a Boolean ndarray `X` of shape (a, b) where

`X[i,j]=any(A[:, i, j] < 0)`

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an intermediate matrix and the `sum(axis)` method:

```
np.random.seed(24)

# example matrix filled either with 0 or -1:
A = np.random.randint(2, size=(3, 2, 2)) - 1

# condition test:
X_elementwise = A < 0

# Check whether the conditions are fullfilled at least once:
X = X_elementwise.sum(axis=0) >= 1
```

Values for A and X:

```
A = array([[[-1,  0],
        [-1,  0]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [ 0, -1]],

       [[ 0,  0],
        [-1,  0]]])

X = array([[ True, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

Comment: Nice. Slight optimization (I think) would be to use np.count_nonzero() instead of sum